# Add data on Firestore database when Flutter app is not open

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, mobile

I'm currently developing a Flutter App to check attendance in school automatically. I have a Firestore database with a collection `users` with an **name**, **class** and a boolean **isPresent**.

I also have a collection `cours` with attributes **subject**, **startTime**, **endTime**, **class**.

And I have a collection `miss` with attributes **user_name**, **user_class**, **cours_subject**, **cours_startTime**, **cours_endTime**.

My problem is that I want to add a user to the 'miss' collection when its field **isPresent** is false between [endTime - 10 minutes;  endTime].

I have implemented a function that adds a user to the 'miss' collection but I don't know when and where to call this function because my app won't be necessary open at that time. So how can I call a function when my app is not open? Do I need to install plugins?

Thank you in advance and don't hesitate to ask me questions if I was not clear

Answer (score -1):

I never did it but i guess you can solve your your problem with a cloud function schedule to run each x time. For instance you can check if everyone is present each 10 minutes from 9am to 9am monday to saturday, and add the people without data to miss colection. Sorry if i didn't understand the problem and the documentation to do this is https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating#target-type.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'll check the documentation to see if this can answer my problem

Comment: Does scheduled cloud function solve you problem?

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response. I think it can be the right solution but I have one more problem. If I understand well Scheduled Cloud Function use Cron jobs. But I would like to schedule my function at a "custom" date that can be endTime and that's where I'm blocked now. Thanks in advance

Comment: But yeah for sure Scheduled Cloud Function is the right method to answer my problem